# mysql select data from 2 tables, but 2nd table has dynamic cell names

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that holds product `names`, `description`, `prices`, etc and another tables were the admin can add custom columns to expand the first table. These columns are create through php forms. I have no way of knowing how many the user will create.

For example my **"products"** tables has:

```
id 
name    
description
price
created
```

and the second table **"products_custom"** has:

```
id
product_id    //this value holds the product id from the above table
serial_number //a custom column the user created
product_image //another column the user created
```

Now, in order to show all these values in a table i have to LEFT JOIN the 2 tables based on the `products.id` and `products_custom.product_id`.

The proper SQL query should be:

```
SELECT p.*, pc.serial_number, pc.product_image FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN products_custom as pc ON p.id = pc.product_id ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

I can get the cell names that exist in the products_custom tables using a php function that queries the 2nd table so having those values in order to use them in the query above is not a problem. I can have these column names returned to a variable.

```
(example: $mycolumns = "serial_number,product_image")
```

The problem is that by accident this query here works as well.

```
SELECT p.*, serial_number,product_image FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN products_custom ON p.id = products_custom.product_id ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Should this be working? Can i leave it like that? or should i add the pc. prefix in every value that `$mycolumns` has and then reconstruct the sql to make it look like the 'proper query' i wrote above?

Thanks in advance !

**FINAL EDIT:**
Based on the answers bellow, to convert the SQL to include pc.prefix from a string of column names:

```
//$whatCol = "serial_number,product_image"; 
$choices = explode(",", $whatCol); 
foreach($choices as &$choice) { 
  $choice = "pc.".mysql_real_escape_string($choice); 
} 
$whatColSQL = implode(",", $choices); 

$prSQL = "SELECT p.*, $whatColSQL FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN products_custom as pc ON p.id = pc.product_id ORDER BY p.id ASC";
```

Comment: I confess I don't understand the problem

Comment: My bad, i wanted to be thorough with my question...To simplify things...
The 'proper sql' query i wrote is using pc. prefix to 'name' the 2nd table.

but in the last sql i wrote, i realized that blindy writing the column names without using pc. also works...which is weird...Shouldnt it also search the 1st table for those columns as well ? why is that sql query working, and could i leave it as it is ?

Comment: If those columns appeared in both tables, then that would create an ambiguity, and the query would fail. So yes, always better to include the table name/table alias with the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use the `pc.` table alias.

The reason it *works* is because those column names are unique to the queried tables.

The reason I say you should use the `pc.` alias is to prevent a possible issue where a user creates a custom column name (in `products_custom`) that is also in the `products` table. For example, `description` or `price`. Without the `pc.` alias a duplicate column name would (should) throw a SQL `Error 1052 Ambiguous`.

Edit: Included and changed some details based on Drew's comment.

Comment: Thats what i thought...It was plain luck that it worked :)

Comment: If a select statement generates a column list with duplicated column names you do not get an error unless you try to refer to them without a table alias (prefix as you call it). In which case the error is `Error 1052 Ambiguous ... `

Comment: @Drew Thanks. Updated the answer to include your info.